# On load, check what #hash tag there is in the url, and then

Tags: javascript

I'd like to load a url with a hashtag and grab it to be used in javascript.

Ie, say you load www.url.com/#1, I would like to be able to do something like the following in JS:

```
var hash_value = get_the_hash_value();

do_something_with(hash_value);
```

How does one perform something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.hash`

Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 22

Comment: Up'd the comment due to the followup addition.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was trying window.location.hash for a while and I thought it wasn't working... turns out it was.

Comment: please add more explanation. filling the answer with nonsense doesn't help